# c# foreach and objects instance

Tags: c#, object, foreach

I am using `foreach` loop and i want to create a new object instance for each loop.

Because when i created an object inside the `foreach` , I found that it use the same object in each loop , not creating new one .

It will be nice to make an array with all those objects but how ?

Comment: Very hard for us to help without the code you already have.

Comment: Maybe you should read the comment at the end of your question.

Comment: there is no code to copy and paste !!! 
it abc question . 
how to creat new object in each foreach loop .
now please take -negative and be smart like mr ( GUY ) 
>>>>>he did answered .

Comment: every time i ask general question i find people just give me negative. 
because there is no code > while others answer the question with out any problem . becuase they know there is no code in such question

Comment: thanks for removing the negative mark

Comment: @abdorefky Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. It doesn't matter that someone answered, that's his business, but as a general rule questions that are open ended and without code are off topic and will be downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the new object in `List`, that way you can have them all at the end of the loop

```
List<object> list = new List<object>();
foreach(...)
{
    object o = new object;
    list.Add(o);
}
```

Now `list` contains all the created objects.

Comment: mmm . the idea of list of objects are great . 
but how to print all variables on the object .

Comment: @abdorefky With `foreach` loop `foreach (object o in list) {Console.WriteLine(o)}`

Comment: `object` of course can be your class and you can print whatever you want from the `o` instance.

Comment: this will print all variables ? .. so how to print only 1 variable from an object from that list

Comment: @abdorefky You can get items by index like an array. `list[0]` will give you the first item.

Comment: should i change object to the name of my class ? 
            List<class1 > routersList1 = new List<class1>();

Comment: last question how to print a particular variable from an object

Comment: @abdorefky `object` is just an example, you can replace it with whatever you want.

Comment: `list[0]` is actually an instance of `class1`

Comment: If you have variable `A` you can do `list[0].A`

Comment: Assuming its public of course.

Comment: Great , sorry for being noob . 
but i can't add any thing to object o . 
when i type ( o. ) i get nothing

Comment: sure public static .

Comment: @abdorefky replace `object` with your class, it was only an example.

Comment: could you vote to my question please ?